# Angular 4 ngModel between components

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to filter my products by categoryId value.
Products are listing in product-component.
I have a categoryFilter pipe that filters Products and returns list of Product.
This pipe requires categoryId but this value is in category-component scope. So my product-component cannot access it. What should I do to make it work?

product-component.html

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let product of products |productFilter:filterText|categoryFilter:filterCategory">
  <button (click)="addToCart(product)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    add to cart
  </button>
  <h5>{{product.productName | uppercase}} ({{product.categoryId}})</h5>
  <p>{{product.quantityPerUnit}}</p>
  <h6>{{product.unitPrice | currency:'TRY':'₺'}} (KDV DAHİL: {{product.unitPrice |vatAdded:8 | currency:'TRY':'₺'}})</h6>
</li>
```

category-component.html

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filterCategory">
<option value="" selected="selected">-- Choose Category --</option>
<option *ngFor="let category of categoryList" value=" 
{{category.categoryId}}">{{category.categoryName}}</option>
</select>
```

category-filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../product/product';

@Pipe({
name: 'categoryFilter'
})
export class CategoryFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: Product[], filterCategory?: any): Product[] {
return filterCategory? 
value.filter((p:Product)=>p.categoryId==filterCategory):value;
 }

}
```

Comment: Are `product-component` and `category-component` siblings? Do they have a parent in common?

Comment: hi @AnkitSharma none of them have a parent. can I access filterCategory(ngModule) value from product-component ?

Comment: No, you may not access the ngModel value. What you can probably do is, use a service to communicate the required data. Please create a demo stackblitz so that we can help you. Thanks

Comment: Can I directly use my branch to create a demo?

Comment: Your branch? Is it on GitHub?

Comment: Yes. I would like to share my updated branch via stackblitz rather than creating from the beginning.

Comment: Yes, pls share the GitHub URL

Comment: https://github.com/bayramorhan/angulardemo/tree/northwind

Comment: Please look at the answer below and let me know if you have any doubts. Thanks

Comment: So I have to listen change event manually right?

Comment: No it is automatically handled. See the ngOnInit of category component and see as soon as it changes the value of category, it reflects in the product component's HTML

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: Yes, It gave me the idea.

Comment: Great, glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may share data between two components that cannot communicate via **Events** by using **services**.

You can inject a service in the two components and access the required field from there. Changing the value of service's field will reflect in both the components.

Please take a look at the below demo to get some sort of idea on how to implement.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prge5p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct.component.ts

Change the value of `appService.category` from `category-component` and it will automatically reflect in the `product-component`.