# access user input from different angular 6 components

Tags: html, angular, typescript, global-variables, angular-components

I am working on a small web game using Angular 6. I have 2 relevant components, play.component and setup.component. The idea is that the user can choose things like difficulty in the setup-component and the user input changes the innerHTML of the elements in the play component. However I don't manage to come up with a way to save the user input in the setup component and access it afterwards from the play component.

I spent some time now looking for my problem and couldn't find anything. If you have alternatives to my solution, please tell me :)

Thanks

Code below

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <p-dropdown [options]="ai" [(ngModel)]="selectedAi" optionLabel="difficulty">
  </p-dropdown>
</div>
<div id="check">
  <p>Do you want to start? <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="begin" binary="true">
    </p-checkbox>
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to access the variables *selectedAI* and *begin* from another component. How do I do it?

Comment: Hold the values in a service instead, and inject the service into your components

Comment: You may refer to the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337309/angular-4-ngmodel-between-components/51337592#51337592

Answer (score 2):

Learn about [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). If you have Parent-child interaction relationship, you should be using

- [@Input](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-input-and-output-example#input) decorator binds a property within one component (child component) to receive a value from another component (parent component). This is one-way communication from parent to child.

**Example** [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41397317/6426617)

```
<user-profile [user]="currentUser"></user-profile> // currentUser value of parent gets binded to user Input decorator
```

Then in the `user-profile` child component definition have `@Input user` to receive value from the parent.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-profile',
  template: '<div>{{user.name}}</div>'
})
export class UserProfile {
  @Input() user;
  constructor() {}
}
```

- [@Output](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-input-and-output-example#input) decorator binds a property of a component to send data from one component (child component) to calling component (parent component). Thione-waye way communication from child to the parent component.

**Example**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-profile',
  template: '<div>{{user.name}}</div>'
})
export class UserProfile {
  @Input() user;
  @Output() countChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
  constructor() {}
  clickChange() {
     this.countChange.emit(value);
  }

}
```

In the html component define

```
<user-profile [user]="currentUser" (countChange)="getCount($event)"></user-profile>
```

If data passing happens within components of the same level. [angular.services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) need to be used.